# Where should I ask about "network diagnostics" resources?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where should I ask about "network diagnostics" resources?

I want to learn more about network diagnostics, and I'm a seasoned developer: But it really feels like my ability to troubleshoot networking related bugs is always hindered by my lack of network diagnostics skills that system administrators tend to have.

When setting up services that talk to one another in a complex software application, I've often seen developers use a series of ad-hoc tricks:

```
netstat -tupln
```

Or

```
telnet myhost myport
```

Or just using [ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29).

Is there a list of best practices for setting up and modifying networking behaviour on Linux systems for software developers? That is, in general, we expect that someone deploying a software application should not need to modify network interfaces, and probably should not need to turn [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) off, but they might need to enable certain iptables rules, etc...

Comment: Sounds too broad for anywhere on the SE network.